# Is the AOT Compilation the default on angular@4.0.0?

Tags: angular-cli, angular

**Is the AOT Compilation the default on angular@4.0.0 and angular/cli@1.0.0 ?**
We are migrating our apps today, and I don't know whether its docs are still valid:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html

I'm having some issues that appears with AoT Compilations errors like that:

> Property 'myModel' is private and only accessible within class 'MyComponent'.

p.s.: It's error only appears with **ng build -target=production**

I think this kind of error should not occur on JIT Compilation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since [`@angular/cli@1.0.0-beta.28`](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/ed5f47dc22d5eb4a5d4b4ae2c8f7cb0ec1a999f3/CHANGELOG.md#100-beta28-2017-02-01) they've made the `AOT` compilation the default for production builds. If you do not want that (even though I strongly advice you for performance reasons to make your app AOT compatible), you can use the `--aot=false` argument for your build command

Comment: using --aot=false uses the JIT compiler rite?

Comment: Yes indeed. And again... not advised on a production build

Comment: JIT compiles in the client, AOT is precompiled. So yes, the resulting JS will differ a lot. JIT is quicker to build, but runs slower. AOT build slower, runs faster