# What is the default compilation for Angular 5? (AOT or JIT)

Tags: angular, angular-cli, jit, angular-aot

On Angular's website, I read that the default compilation is JIT:

[image]

https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler

I guess when it's on the official Angular website, it has to be JIT but on many other pages, I read that AOT is the default compilation in Angular 5.

This confuses me a little.  In this question it also says that AOT is the default: [Is the AOT Compilation the default on angular@4.0.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43007872/is-the-aot-compilation-the-default-on-angular4-0-0)

What is true now?

Comment: JIT is the default. To use AOT compilation, you need to add the `--aot` flag, and for the record, this flag is included in the `--prod` one.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Read carefully the answer that you've linked.

> they've made the AOT compilation the default for **production** builds.

- `ng serve` is JiT
- `ng serve -prod` is AoT
- `ng build` is JiT
- `ng build -prod` is AoT

Comment: (Rules of Linux : flags with characters have a single hyphen, flags with string have two. Even though this works, use `--prod`, not `-prod`, you'll thank me someday)

Comment: This is straight from the `ng s --help` `--target (String) (Default: development) Defines the build target.
    aliases: -t <value>, -dev (--target=development), -prod (--target=production), --target <value>`

Comment: Again, I totally understand, as I said it works, I'm just saying that most of the time it will be two hyphens, so one should might aswell get used to it.