# Is AOT (ahead of time) the default compilation in Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular2-aot

I have read in a tutorial that says AOT the default compilation in Angular 5 and above. I am a bit confused about this. I searched on the internet and couldn't find a precise answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is the AOT Compilation the default on angular@4.0.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43007872/is-the-aot-compilation-the-default-on-angular4-0-0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is for production. For development (ng serve) the default is JIT... to change to 'aot' you have to either add to your angular.json, under the project, serve, options, the option

```
options {
    "aot": true,
}
```

or simply use `ng serve --aot`